# set current database postgres in c++

Tags: postgresql, odbc, libpq

The subject is the exact line I tried for Google.

Unfortunately the return from starts with "How to RETRIEVE table name in Postgres".

And then couple of following talks about using psql.

So hopefully someone here will help - "From the C++ code with libpq or ODBC" how do I set the current working database?

I guess I'm looking for a standard SELECT query or some PG-specific command I can execute to change the `cwd (Current Working Database)`.

Comment: You don't "set" the current database, you _connect_ to it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, in psql you issue `\c` in order to change the current database (yes, by connecting to it). Is there an equivalent?

Comment: `\connect` simply _connects_ to a different database using the username from the existing connection. The "current" database for a connection is always the one you connect to. You can not "change" that without creating a completely new connection.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, in SQL Server you issue `USE 《db_name》` to change the current DB. Is there an equivalent? Because it's what `\c` does - connects to different DB or changes the current DB. I think it just semantics...

Comment: Postgres is not SQL Server. The architecture of both databases are fundamentally different.  You can **not** _change_ the current database in Postgres. You **have** to create a new physical connection. The name of the `\command` is not just "semantics". It _disconnects_ the current connection and creates a brand new one.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I understand. But from the user/developer perspective the meaning of both are the same - change the current database on the connection {handle}. After executing the command on their respective DBMS all queries issued wil be executed in the `current/used/connected` database

Comment: No they are not the same. Postgres is not SQL Server. You need to migrate your mindset too.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, of course they are not. They are even produced by 2 completely different companies/communities. What I meant is that the meaning if the `USE` and `\c` commands aere the same - change the current database to the new one. Whether the current means used or connected is irrelevant - in the end it means that every query issued will be executed in the context of the `current` database, or the one chosen by `USE` or `\c`. You are speaking from the DBMS context, I'm talking from the developer perspective.

Comment: No. `USE` and `\connect` are two completely different things. USE is a SQL command understood (and run) by the database server. `\connect` is a **psql** meta command that is just a wrapper around disconnect/connect implemented in psql and only available in within psql. There is no support to "change the database" through a SQL command in Postgres.  Other SQL clients (e.g. pgAdmin, ,DBeaver, HeidSQL, ...) do not support `\connect`.